# display block causing problems in firefox

Tags: html, alignment

I have a table in html
inside that table i have two rows 
like
`<table>`
`<tr>`
`<td></td>`
`<td> </td>`
`.`
`.`
`.`
`<td>`
`</td>`

`</tr>`
`<tr>`
`</tr>`
`table`

Problem is whenever I set the style as `<tr display:block>` alignment is messing up in Firefox but it works fine in IE only. Anyone please help? I have google a lot and could not find the solution. I have set `%` to my `td` tags

Comment: Shouldn't you use `<tr style="display:block;">` instead?

Comment: yeah.. I used only `<tr style="display:block;">`   Sorry it was a typo above

Comment: It's really hard to say anything constructive, because you haven't supplied enough information about your problem. "Alignment is messing up"? That could mean a whole bunch of things=) Try to clearify your question.

Comment: I got my answer after hard try.. anyway, Thank you.

Comment: the solution is to remove the style in html and add it in javscript and i made it as 'display:table-row' which worked for me in all the browsers.

Comment: Why do you have to use javascript for this? Why not use `<style type="text/css">table { display:table-row; }</style>` in the `head` section of your page or in an external stylesheet?

Answer (score 1):

**This is the solution ,**

To display `tr`,  use `display:table-row` instead of `display:block` .

To display `td`,  use `display:table-cell` instead of `display:block` .